Cleaning VSCode profiles Folder & Workspaces
I recently set up a new VS Code profile, which I intend to use for specific projects. However, while doing so, I noticed that, in the Default profile, the "Workspaces & Folders" section is polluted with a bunch of paths that no longer exist. I saw this was recently raised as an issue in the VS Code GitHub (link) and it looks like the feature has been implemented to remove them, as there's now a small x next to profiles. However, for me, the x is grayed out and I cannot click it for any of the workspaces. I think it's because it is the default profile (as I can click the x to remove workspaces from my new profile).
I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I am simply doing something wrong. If it is a bug, is there another way to remove these? I'm not sure where these paths are stored in VS Code.
I tried deleting all the folders in C:\Users\charles.wetaski\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage, but the paths still remain in the default profile.
Update: I raised a bug ticket here

To the close-voter (and CV queue reviwers): VS Code is quite clearly a "tool used by programmers," so this question is most certainly on-topic.

I suggest you to also raise a bug ticket. if you do, please add a link here to your ticket.

I can confirm the same behavior: open "Profiles" page, a lot of paths listed under "Folder & Workspaces" (many of them temporary ones I deleted long ago), the small x on the right is displayed but doesn't work (grayed out).
However, I might have found a way to clear them all: goto "run command" and find "Developer: Reset Workspace Profiles Associations". That is very brute force, so hopefully the x will be working soon ...
My VSCode version is 1.95.3
